# How to add multiple variables on the same line with string in between?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a nought and crosses game (also called tic tac toe in the us). To make the board, I need to have multiple variables on the same line with strings in between them. This is what I have tried:

```
Print (var1, + ' | ' + , var2, + ' | ' + , var3)
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is all the variables of same string type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it without comma just do:

```
print var1 + var2 + "|" + var3
```

If the var is not string then you can use:

```
str(var)
```

to convert it to string and use the + operator as string concatenation

Answer (score 4):

Firstly the `print` keyword is lower case.

Secondly, when you are wanting to format your output it's best to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting). Or in this specific case probably just using the [join method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) of strings will work best.

```
print(' | '.join([var1, var2, var3]))
```

Or if they aren't strings..

```
print(' | '.join(str(v) for v in [var1, var2, var3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
print(' | '.join([var1, var2, var3]))
```

Please use this, if variable is of not string type

```
print(' | '.join(map(str, [var1, var2, var3])))
```